# How to transform HTML To XML swift

Tags: html, swift, xml

I have file.html in my app and I want to convert it into xml.

Is it possible to convert file.html file into file.xml in swift(Xcode)?

I tried to find the answer but didn't find any helpful resources. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You could change the extension from `html` to `xml` and hope it works. Other than that we can't say without knowing what the contents look like in the `html` file and what you want it to look like in the `xml` file.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have sample files available and both are same except xml one has `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mono> </mono>`. Hope it helps.